# How to symbolicate iPhone \ iPad crash logs?

Tags: iphone, symbolicatecrash

I would like to know how to symbolicate crashes in XCode, i have .crash files and i don't know how to do it.

I want to fix a damn bug that affects my app, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The App needs to be built **without** stripping debug symbols:

[image: debug_symbols]

then, when it crashes on a device, go into the organizer window,  under the "Device Logs" section, and you should see a nice symbolicated crash log:

[image]

---

To import the crash logs into Xcode (from, say, an email), just drag it into the organizer window like so:

[image]

Comment: Damn, i would have not say it better than this. Thank ya! :D

Comment: I uploaded my app to the app store and now the app crashed on my client's device after apple approves it so he sent me the crash log... Any idea how I can symbolicate it?

Comment: @Pr You probably cannot since it was built as a release version with symbols stripped out.

Answer (score 2):

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

> With the latest version of Xcode (3.2.2), you can drag and drop any crash reports into the Device Logs section of the Xcode Organiser and they will automatically by symbolicated for you. I think this works best if you built that version of the App using Build & Archive (also part of Xcode 3.2.2)

Comment: You're totally right, this functionality could have been taken out of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You need the .xcarchive files of the application from which you received the crash file

1. From .xcarchive we pull out MyApp.app, MyApp-dSYM.dSYM and MyApp-Crash-log.crash, create a folder on the desktop and the treasure and put them.
2. Open the terminal and write the following commands(Replace **MyApp** with your names):

   - `cd Desktop/MyApp`
   - `export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
   - `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v MyApp.crash MyApp.app.dSYM`