# iOS App crashed on NSURLConnection with log, but i cannot repeat, help me

Tags: ios, crash, nsurlconnection

I cannot repeat the crash, but submit the app to apple, always with the same crash log. Please help me to analyze what's the problem. detail crash log are give below. Thanks a lot!

The apple test team tips that:
This occurred when your app was used: 
- On Wi-Fi 
- On cellular network

```
Date/Time:       2013-02-01 11:32:40.293 -0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.1 (10B143)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00760040
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                             0x00760040 0 + 7733312
1   ProtocolBuffer                  0x3866d1b6 -[PBRequester connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 1042
2   Foundation                      0x33bb7912 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 14
3   Foundation                      0x33af7764 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
4   Foundation                      0x33af7680 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
5   CFNetwork                       0x32f5864c ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 24
6   CFNetwork                       0x32f57d30 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 52
7   CFNetwork                       0x32f80010 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 16
8   CoreFoundation                  0x331c1aca CFArrayApplyFunction + 174
9   CFNetwork                       0x32f8046e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
10  CFNetwork                       0x32ee445e MultiplexerSource::perform() + 186
11  CoreFoundation                  0x332508f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33250158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3324ef2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
14  CoreFoundation                  0x331c2238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
15  CoreFoundation                  0x331c20c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
16  GraphicsServices                0x36da0336 GSEventRunModal + 70
17  UIKit                           0x350de2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
18  Maoye                           0x00003ca2 0x1000 + 11426
19  Maoye                           0x00003c5c 0x1000 + 11356

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b460d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3aead6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4505d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b38bd22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b387374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b460d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3aead6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b44fe30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b44ffd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x332502b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3324f02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x331c2238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x331c20c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x391c1390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b90de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b8fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: URLConnection
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4505d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b38b94e _dispatch_update_kq + 178
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b38734c _dispatch_mgr_wakeup + 40
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b3899a8 _dispatch_wakeup + 20
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b389938 _dispatch_queue_push_list_slow2 + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b389afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b387678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b38a610 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 208
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b38a7d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae7ee _pthread_wqthread + 358
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b44fe30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b44ffd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x332502b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3324f02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x331c2238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x331c20c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x33ae65be -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Maoye                           0x0003aab2 0x1000 + 236210
8   Maoye                           0x0007fbc8 0x1000 + 519112
9   Maoye                           0x00034958 0x1000 + 211288
10  Maoye                           0x00036656 0x1000 + 218710
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b90de _pthread_start + 306
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b8fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b44fe30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b44ffd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x332502b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3324f02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x331c2238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x331c20c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x33b0f888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x33b9322c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b90de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b8fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b460d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3aead6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3ae680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b45f2cc __connect + 8
1   Maoye                           0x00027b7a 0x1000 + 158586
2   Maoye                           0x00029e0a 0x1000 + 167434
3   Maoye                           0x00029db8 0x1000 + 167352
4   Maoye                           0x000078da 0x1000 + 26842
5   Maoye                           0x00009bd6 0x1000 + 35798
6   Maoye                           0x0003408e 0x1000 + 209038
7   Maoye                           0x00036656 0x1000 + 218710
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b90de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b8fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4606a4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3be1be nanosleep + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b41ee4e sleep + 42
3   Maoye                           0x0001e190 0x1000 + 119184
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b90de _pthread_start + 306
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b8fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b460594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33254474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b90de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3b8fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000001    r1: 0x01090350      r2: 0x00760041      r3: 0x00000007
    r4: 0x38d2fa5e    r5: 0x01090350      r6: 0x00000001      r7: 0x2fdfed0c
    r8: 0x01090340    r9: 0x0109b240     r10: 0x0026b5d4     r11: 0x0109b0f0
    ip: 0x3cf1b7f0    sp: 0x2fdfece8      lr: 0x0003b439      pc: 0x00760040
  cpsr: 0x200f0030
```

Comment: Have you tested to see what happens with an internet connection is lost right before you attempt to connect? (can test in airplane mode). Based on their tips that does not seem to be the issue but you could check.

Comment: I'm gonna assume your app's name is "`Maoye`".  It might be helpful to you and to us if [you symbolicate your crash log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172887/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-ipad-crash-logs).

Comment: All the conditions include wifi, 3g, gprs, airplane, i also opened the network link conditioner and test for each one. but i cannot repeat the crash

Answer (score 0):

I guess your crash is in the method connectionDidFinishLoading. As crash is in Thread 0 ,the starting two lines give description about the crash. This is what I know from my friend who is a tester.

1   ProtocolBuffer                  0x3866d1b6 -[PBRequester connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 1042

Comment: I used IconDownloader, and i checked the connectionDidFinishLoading method many times, i used it in other projects which all are ok and passed, maybe i need the replace it with another method?

Comment: @DanielWu connectionDidFinishLoading is a delegate method so no need to replace it. No idea as to what's wrong in there. Hope u find it.