# XCode 5 symbolicate crash logs

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode5

I'm finding some issues regarding to symbolification, I have an app that is not yet published in the App Store.

I've been doing some tests with iPads iOS 6 and iOS 7,and their crash logs always appear in hexadecimal.

As I understand if you are using XCode v.4or up (im using Xcode 5)  , in order to correct this you have to build the app (⌘ B) then archive it (Menu >Product > Archive ) . Am I missing something? Like changing the scheme or selecting other option besides Build and Run...

I tried this post [How to symbolicate iPhone \ iPad crash logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172887/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-ipad-crash-logs?lq=1) they said that you have to make sure that  Build Settings in Deployment, Strip Debug Symbols During Copy  and Strip Linked Product ...the values of Debug and Release have to be set NO and YES respectively. Like I said I tried this but it failed.

I would appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have set build Options "Debug Infomartion Format" --> "DWARF with dSYM file", It can not be symbolic without DSYM.

Comment: Yes, I checked it and it's set both in Debug and Release. Am I missing some step after that?