# how to remove detailed crash logs

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports

Hi i got crash report from apple and i am not understand the crash report,please helpme folks.
crash reports is below-

```
{"app_name":"JobDiagnosis","app_version":"1.12","bundleID":"com.jobdiagnosis.com.free","adam_id":502436374,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1 (12B411)","slice_uuid":"f6779c3b-c956-3e22-9026-49e7e9f27d1d","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1.12","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"JobDiagnosis"}
Incident Identifier: 778AF40B-A9AB-438D-94AC-A463B9F60511
CrashReporter Key:   bd0e0d2428c1a2d1c7d56e9405b5cc5ce7961b21
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             JobDiagnosis [1367]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DCF81005-2368-4AA1-8A8C-6ED64EAB10D0/JobDiagnosis.app/JobDiagnosis
Identifier:          com.jobdiagnosis.com.free
Version:             1.12 (1.12)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-08 11:35:04.432 -0800
Launch Time:         2014-11-08 11:34:54.447 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Comment: that states that your accessing the released memory address...

Comment: /questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports check this

Comment: not understand,please elobrate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172887/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-ipad-crash-logs

Comment: is that your mail is compatible to iOS 8 and run your iOS 8 device

Comment: not understand,how i remove crash

Comment: i coded only for location in ios8

Comment: In your ios 8.1 device the code running fine or not … and you cann't remove these logs because this is coming from iOS

Comment: running fine in ios 8 also but in location delegate always call error

Comment: Check that what error and the crashed device is iOS 8.1, you can get a clue

Comment: <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.

Comment: did u used uiwebview or uifont in your code

Comment: when i change the alignment from horizontal to vertical ,its occur 3 times