# My app workes fin in my device but crash in Apple test couldn't find the reason

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

I tested my iOS app thoroughly in my device and there ware no crash but when I submitted the app for release it crashes repeatedly. I tried to analyze I couldn't find the reason. When I look the creash log it looks crash happens in

```
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyAppName [14002]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6ED37E47-5605-432E-B077-B6B109B9FE1B/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
Identifier:          com.mydomain.MyAppName
Version:             1 (1.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       10B63
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mydomain.MyAppName [5310]
```

```
Date/Time:           2019-03-07 09:24:56.9034 -0800
Launch Time:         2019-03-07 09:20:00.9801 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)
Baseband Version:    7.32.00
Report Version:      104
```

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x182ef1ea4 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1820c1a50 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   UIKitCore                       0x1af72def0 -[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 2691
3   UIKitCore                       0x1af736f28 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 2195
4   UIKitCore                       0x1af7348ac __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 479
5   UIKitCore                       0x1afddc87c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 295
6   UIKitCore                       0x1afdca878 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 383
7   UIKitCore                       0x1afdf9880 _afterCACommitHandler + 131
8   CoreFoundation                  0x182e816bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 31
9   CoreFoundation                  0x182e7c350 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 411
10  CoreFoundation                  0x182e7c8f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
11  CoreFoundation                  0x182e7c0e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 435
12  GraphicsServices                0x1850f5584 GSEventRunModal + 99
13  UIKitCore                       0x1afdd0c00 UIApplicationMain + 211
14  MyAppName                       0x100e601fc main + 33276 (ChildInfoViewController.swift:15)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x18293abb4 start + 3
```

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182a87104 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182b03020 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001829ded78 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001820a8f78 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001820a9120 default_unexpected_handler+ 8480 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001820c1e58 _objc_terminate+ 28248 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001820b50fc std::__terminate(void (*)+ 57596 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001820b4cec __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001820c1c20 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182e7c14c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001850f5584 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001afdd0c00 UIApplicationMain + 212
12  MyAppName                       0x0000000100e601fc main + 33276 (ChildInfoViewController.swift:15)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018293abb4 start + 4
```

Comment: First try to [read crash log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172887/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-ipad-crash-logs). for more info [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not belong to any particular problem.

Comment: What do you do on line 15 of `ChildInfoViewController`?  Have you tried running a TestFlight build?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt attention. I tried to understand crash log but I couldn't find any clue in it. Since this is the first time I am facing a problem like this I am expecting more help to trace the problem from the community.

Comment: @Paulw11 I checked it nothing interesting code is in it. Interestingly I don't call the class when the crash happens

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to present a popover either from or containing `ChildInfoViewController`. Something is going wrong with that.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I tested in TestFlight but it doesn't crash

Comment: Are you testing on iPhone, iPod, and iPad?

Comment: Did you test on an iPad?  Apple typically reviews apps on an iPad.

Comment: @SachinVas I am testing in Phone but tested in iPad simulator too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644054/uiactivityviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios-8-ipads. Looks like its this issue.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't load ChildInfoViewController in the code where it crashes. That is my main issue

Comment: but it crashed *in* `ChildInfoViewController`